# Set custom cpu string for qemu/kvm

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, qemu, cpu-architecture

I have some virtual machines with software, which licensing check depends on cpu string.
They're running on kvm - with default cpu string value - which is `QEMU Virtual CPU version 1.7.1`

After upgrading host server to newer version of debian - cpu string changed to `QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.0.0` - what break license check.

Is any way (excluding recompiling/downgrading qemu/kvm) to force for specific virtual machine using cpu string `QEMU Virtual CPU version 1.7.1` ?